# orbitcontrols.js: How to Zoom In/ Zoom Out

Tags: javascript, three.js

Using orbitcontrols.js (with THREE.js), I want to achieve the same effect in code as rotating the mouse wheel. For example, I want to call something like camera.zoomIn() and have it move a set distance toward the target. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>From looking at the source code you can call `.dollyIn(dollyScale)` and `.dollyOut(dollyScale)` on the `OrbitalControls` object.</s>

Edit: these aren't public methods; one can access them by editing `OrbitalControls.js` though.

I added `this.dIn = dollyIn;` to the `THREE.OrbitControls` function, I can now zoom in by calling `controls.dIn(1.05); controls.update();` from outside.

Comment: Thanks Chris, you mean this

    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

followed by something like this

    controls.dollyIn(.5);

right? I get an Object doesn't support property or method error. I've tried every combination I an imagine including a direct call to dollyIn since it is not a member of the OrbitControls object, and I always get the same result.

Answer (score 7):

At least for simple cases, you can change the position of the *camera* (e.g. multiply `x`, `y` and `z` by a factor), which automagically updates the `OrbitControls`.

Example with a `<input type="range">` slider:

```
zoomer.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    var zoomDistance = Number(zoomer.value),
        currDistance = camera.position.length(),
        factor = zoomDistance/currDistance;

    camera.position.x *= factor;
    camera.position.y *= factor;
    camera.position.z *= factor;
});
```

https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/yPZQMV

Comment: Hello sir, your answer is amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can set values on [OrbitControls.maxDistance](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.maxDistance) and [OrbitControls.minDistance](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.minDistance) to zoom in and out programmatically.

For example, if you wanted to animate a zoom out with [gsap](https://greensock.com/gsap/) you could do something like this:

```
gsap.to(myOrbitControls, {
    minDistance: 20, // target min distance
    duration: 1,
    overwrite: 'auto',
    ease: 'power1.inOut',
    onComplete: () => {
        myOrbitControls.minDistance = 0 // reset to initial min distance
    },
})
```