# Programmatically zoom OrbitControls

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, zooming

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to zoom an `OrbitControls` with `Three.JS`.

I have looked through the source many times and I can see methods called `dollyIn()` and `dollyOut()` but I can't access them from my own code.

I have tried the method `.zoom` but it does nothing.

Is it possible to zoom by code?

Comment: See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/9005/files

Comment: @WestLangley It gives me the following error: `controls.rotateCameraUp is not a function`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [orbitcontrols.js: How to Zoom In/ Zoom Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198618/orbitcontrols-js-how-to-zoom-in-zoom-out)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856907/three-js-orbitcontrols-js-invoking-zoom-in-out-with-button-controls-dollyout